# Один запрос или несколько, как оптимальнее?

Tags: php, mysql

Страница написана на PHP с применением MySQL. 4 разных типа данных из 1 таблицы при помощи 4 запросов.

Будет ли правильно сделать один запрос к БД и потом его фильтровать силами PHP на странице, или лучше оставить как есть, т.е. делать 4 запроса, но каждый извлекает только ту информацию, которая нужна?

Comment: Поясните критерии правильности, то есть какими параметрами следует руководствоваться при выборе подхода.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет сделать один запрос и не фильтровать данные на странице.

Делать один запрос с последующей фильтрацией плохо - мало сколько там данных будет Может там несколько миллионов записей.

Делать 4 отдельных запроса - также не очень хорошо. Все таки каждый запрос отнимает время. Но если результаты маленькие, то их можно закешировать и решить проблему.

Comment: Почему правильно будет "не фильтровать"? Время лишнее может и займет, но потом с таким набором удобнее намного работать будет же. Тем более если у меня много записей и мне надо на странице в одном месте одно отображать, в другом - другое, а в третьем - третье. Проще же раз по массиву пробежаться и раскидать все по полочкам, чем потом 4 раза по этому массиву бегать. Можно, конечно, на выходе отсортировать по требуемому признаку, но выборка нужных значений излишне усложнит логику выборки требуемого результата.

Comment: @BOPOH не выгодно фильтровать на PHP потому, что этот код будет компилироваться из PHP в си, а в mysql фильтрация самостоятельная и быстрая (и прожорливая, да).

Answer (score -1):

Ты в обед тоже таким вопросом задаешся - по отдельности все съесть, или второе навалить в суп, полить сверху компотом, а в желудке все переварится?

Оптимальнее всегда извлекать только то что нужно.

Хотя 4 запроса к одной таблице - это тоже ерунда. Или таблица кривая, или запросы.

Возможно здесь просто нужен в запросе оператор IN(...).

Comment: То есть оптимальнее взять ложку и каждый раз бегать на кухню к повару набирать в нее суп из котла и бежать с ней обратно чтобы съесть за столом? )

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы вы сменили тон ответа. Сейчас такое пренебрежение, позиция с высока и фамильярность только отталкивают, даже при наличии рационального зерна.